# For loop only iterating one object from list using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

For loop only iterating one object from the list provided by the function. Below are the code and terminal logs.

Note:- I want to delete both the URLs which are the part of below list

function `delete_index_url()` output is like :-

```
['https://vpc.xxx.es.amazonaws.com/staging-logs-2019.09.13', 'https://vpc.xxx.es.amazonaws.com/staging-logs-2019.09.16']
```

```
def clean_index( ):
  delete_urls = delete_index_url()    # above function output assign to variable
  for i in delete_urls:
        print(i)   <-- this only print "https://vpc.xxx.es.amazonaws.com/staging-logs-2019.09.13"
        try:
          req = requests.delete(i)
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
            print ('ERROR: Not able to connect to URL')
            return 0
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
            print ('ERROR: ElasticSearch time out')
            return 0
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
            print ('ERROR: HTTP error')
            return 0
        else:
            print ('INFO: ElasticSearch response status code was %s' % req.status_code)

            if req.status_code != 200:
               return 0
            else:
               return 1

print(clean_index())
```

Logs output from a python script:-

```
INFO: Sorting indexes
['https://vpc.xxx.es.amazonaws.com/staging-logs-2019.09.13', 'https://vpc.xxx.es.amazonaws.com/staging-logs-2019.09.16']
INFO: Getting a list of indexes
INFO: ElasticSearch response status code was 200
INFO: Found 200 indexes
INFO: Sorting indexes
https://vpc.xxx.es.amazonaws.com/staging-logs-2019.09.13  # only 2019.09.13, not 2019.09.16 logs URLs
```

Comment: did you print `delete_urls` list before the `for` loop n check ?

Comment: It looks like you have both `return 0` and `return 1`. One of those will execute, so you will return immediately after processing just the first item.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning `0 or 1` and ending the function right away, you can create a list and store the responses and return it:

```
def clean_index( ):
  responses = []
  delete_urls = delete_index_url()    # above function output assign to variable
  for i in delete_urls:
        print(i)   
        try:
          req = requests.delete(i)
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
            print ('ERROR: Not able to connect to URL')
            responses.append(0)
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
            print ('ERROR: ElasticSearch time out')
            responses.append(0)
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
            print ('ERROR: HTTP error')
            responses.append(0)
        else:
            print ('INFO: ElasticSearch response status code was %s' % req.status_code)
            if req.status_code != 200:
               responses.append(0)
            else:
               responses.append(1)
    return responses
print(clean_index())
```